# Django Rest Framework 2.4 TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_none'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is kind of weird, I get this error
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_none'
on DRF 2.4 but it works fine in DRF 2.3.14

It seems to be something with the validation in the model because I tried with the ProductImg Model and it works fine, so I know there is something wrong in the model, I even tried only getting the id, but I always get the same error message, for now I guess my only option is to use DRF's previous version, I would like to get an opinion before reporting a bug, as it is the first time I use DRF

**constants.py**

```
GENDER =(
    ('woman', 'Woman'),
    ('man', 'Man'),
    ('none', 'None'),
)

PRODUCT_TYPE =(
    ('top','Top'),
    ('bottom','Bottom'),
    ('dress','Dress'),
    ('accessories', 'accessories'),
)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

**models.py***

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER, max_length=10)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155, verbose_name=_('Category'))
    type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, related_name='categories_for', verbose_name=_('Category type'))
    meta_description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Meta Description'))
    meta_keywords = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Meta Keywords'))
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='children', verbose_name=_('Category Parent'), blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, verbose_name=_('URL alias'))



class Trends(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Trends'))
    banner = ProcessedImageField(verbose_name=_('Banner'), upload_to='trends', blank=True, processors=[ResizeToFit(width='1200', upscale=False)], format='JPEG', options={'quality': 70})
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Description'))
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    pubDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('Date published'))
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER, max_length=10)
    promoted = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Promoted'), default=False)

class Product(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_('Reference'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Product Name'))
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name=_('Product Description'))
    color_code = models.CharField(max_length=11, verbose_name=_('Color Code'))
    color_web = models.CharField(max_length=7, verbose_name=_('Web Color'))
    size = models.CharField(max_length=11, verbose_name=_('Product Size'))
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Product Price'))
    price_promo = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('Product Promo Price'))
    upc = models.CharField(max_length=155, verbose_name=_('UPC'))
    stock = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Product Stock'))
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=_('Estilo'))
    in_stores = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('Product Availability'))
    try_out = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Try out Product'))
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='', blank=True, verbose_name=_('URL alias'))
    blog = models.URLField(blank=True, verbose_name=_('Blog mention link'))
    parent_product = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Main Product'))
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('Active'))
    trends = models.ManyToManyField(Trends, verbose_name=_('Trends'), blank=True)
    photoshoot_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Photoshoot ID'))
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/jav/vn-azulu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 200, in __init__
self.fields = self.get_fields()
File "/Users/jav/vn-azulu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 236, in get_fields
default_fields = self.get_default_fields()
File "/Users/jav/vn-azulu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 721, in get_default_fields
field = self.get_field(model_field)
File "/Users/jav/vn-azulu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 910, in get_field
return ModelField(model_field=model_field, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jav/vn-azulu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 400, in __init__
super(ModelField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_none'
```

Comment: Please provide your Trends, and your Category models. I tried to reproduce your issue. w/ those two attributes commented out, and could not do so.

Comment: k, so getting closer. Still need Trends.ProcessImageField && ResizeToFit && GENDER. Note: I created a GENDER tuple and commented out the Trends.banner line, and I cannot reproduce your error. Also note `type` is a python builtin. It is a bad-idea to name your model attributes `type`. i.e. ProductType.type && Category.type. ( modify those if you can )

Comment: @JeffSheffield Thanks for the tip I'll change that right away, I added the Gender Tuple, ProcessImageField as well as ResizeToFit are part of [Imagekit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit), I asume the methods and properties in the model don't contribute to the mistake right?

Comment: no, I am running with the names ProductType.type, and Category.type, and it is serializing just fine. I will play with Imagekit tomorrow (thats a new lib for me).At this point I have 3 guesses.. ( and they are just that, guesses) 1: it could be your GENDER tuple should look like this `((0, 'Woman'),(1, 'Man'),(2, 'None'),)` and 2: I would comment out the Trends.banner line. Does your data serialize if you comment out that line in the model? 3: bad-data... can you clear out your dbms.. and re-stimulate in some data? Does the issue go away?

Comment: I'll try that right now, and let you know thanks for all your help!

Comment: Yea sure.. I have a pretty good 'clean' test env set up with both drf 2.4 and 2.3. So we should be able to walk in on it. Note: the initialization of `drf:fields.py:class WritableField(Field):` changed between those 2 versions of drf. Actually... I bet... that ImageKit module is using the `allow_none` keyword in its model create. ( going to check that out now )

Comment: what version of django are you running?

Comment: Im running Django 1.6.5

Comment: Do you have [pilkit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/pilkit) installed..? The call to `ResizeToFit` sucks in that dependency.

Comment: Yeah, I should have let you know, here is the import I use, from pilkit.processors import ResizeToFill, ResizeToFit

Comment: just tried the clean data approach, cleaned all the db out, same error

Comment: I just Isolated the issue, I was using [modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) all models with translation fields generate the error when being serialized

Comment: I am glad you found it! I should have mentioned that I was converting the translation stuff from  `verbose_name=_('string')` to `verbose_name='string'` when I was trying to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to reproduce the issue: I cannot reproduce it, if I remove the [django model translation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) stuff.

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=155, verbose_name=_('Category'))
```

becomes

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=155, verbose_name='Category')
```

When doing this for all of your models, and stimulating data. The data serializes just fine.

Comment: Jeff thanks for all your help, yes it's definitely something with model translation, however I need i18n for the project so for now I'll stick to DRF2.3.14which serializes all the data

Comment: Yea, I'm digging around a bit.. to see where we need to submit a defect.

Comment: For reference, this bug is being discussed in this DRF issue: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1809

Comment: This has been fixed in DRF 2.4.3